# Mathematica 13.0 appears to automatically reverse nested series which contain logarithms. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Tags: series-expansion

When performing manipulations on nested series, I need the series to retain the nesting order I originally defined.  In Mathematica versions 8.0 and 10.4, this was almost always the default behavior.  However, I recently started using Mathematica 13.0 and found that this was no longer the case.  The problem appears to occur whenever a Log[] term is introduced.  For instance, see the following example:

```
test=SeriesData[x, 0, {SeriesData[e, 0, {5, 0, Rational[-15, 2], 0, Rational[15, 8], 0, Rational[5, 16], 0, Rational[15, 128]}, 0, 9, 1], 0, SeriesData[e, 0, {-6, 0, 24, 0, Rational[-99, 4], 0, Rational[21, 4], 0, Rational[51, 64]}, 0, 9, 1], SeriesData[e, 0, {3 a, 0, Rational[-39, 2] a, 0, Rational[189, 8] a, 0, Rational[-87, 16] a, 0, Rational[-111, 128] a}, 0, 9, 1], SeriesData[e, 0, {2 (Rational[-9, 2] + Rational[-3, 2] a^2), 0, 3 (9 + Rational[3, 2] a^2) + 2 (6 + Rational[15, 4] a^2), 0, 2 (Rational[45, 8] + Rational[-45, 16] a^2) + 3 (Rational[-117, 16] + Rational[-9, 4] a^2), 0, 2 (Rational[-165, 16] + Rational[15, 32] a^2) + 3 (Rational[-51, 8] + Rational[9, 16] a^2), 0, 2 (Rational[345, 128] + Rational[15, 256] a^2) + 3 (Rational[873, 256] + Rational[3, 32] a^2)}, 0, 9, 1], SeriesData[e, 0, {30 a, 0, (-138) a, 0, Rational[393, 4] a, 0, Rational[99, 2] a, 0, Rational[-1857, 64] a}, 0, 9, 1], SeriesData[e, 0, {3 a^2 + 2 (Rational[-27, 2] + Rational[-31, 2] a^2), 0, 3 (36 + Rational[45, 2] a^2) + 2 (9 + Rational[123, 4] a^2), 0, 3 (Rational[-111, 8] + Rational[-105, 4] a^2) + 2 (Rational[249, 8] + Rational[-123, 16] a^2), 0, 2 (Rational[-375, 16] + Rational[-413, 32] a^2) + 3 (Rational[-75, 2] + Rational[-91, 16] a^2), 0, 2 (Rational[-1575, 128] + Rational[1125, 256] a^2) + 3 (Rational[45, 128] + Rational[93, 16] a^2)}, 0, 9, 1]}, 3, 10, 1];
```

We can perform standard operations on this series such as multiplication/addition and keep x as the outer series without a problem.  However, if we try the following operations

```
Print[test+Log[x]];
Print[ExpandAll[test+Log[x]]];
Print[ExpandAll[test+Log[x]*e^4*x^3]];
test[[3,1]]+=Log[x];
Print[test];
test[[3,1]]+=Log[e];
Print[test];
```

we find that all but the first rearrange the series so that e is on the outside.

This is a problem for my code, which involves a great number of series manipulations involving log terms.  Thus far, I have been addressing the issue by manually going into logarithms and substituting in a dummy variable like "xx" for x.  However, this is far from ideal, and it would be much simpler if I could change the behavior in a more universal manner.  Otherwise, I may just have to stick with the older versions of Mathematica.

Comment: My guess is that you're out of luck, since `With[{s = ReplacePart[test, {3, 1} -> test[[3, 1]] + Log[x]]},
 ReplacePart[s, {3, 1} -> s[[3, 1]] + Log[e]]
 ]` has `x` on the outside, but if we replace `Log[e] -> 0` in it, it automatically reverts to `e` on the outside.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that might be the case.  This new behavior seems rather curious.  I wonder what was changed in the Series functionality to have it check for Log terms and then reevaluate like this.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  Does this help? `Collect[test, e]` or this: `Map[Simplify, Collect[test, e], 2]` or this `Map[Simplify[Collect[#, a]] &, Collect[test, x], 2]`?  You might also take a look at `ComplexityFunction`

Comment: Also, instead of manually inserting a dummy variable, you could do this: `expr = expr/.x->xx`